# Download all files and folders from document library to local directory o365 powershell csom

Tags: document-library, powershell, csom

I have a document library on Office 365 which I want to download to my local directory via powershell csom. I want to keep the file structure so its exactly the same in my local directory as it is in my Office 365 document library
I found this which is what I want but its not in CSOM

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $webUrl
$list = $web.GetList($listUrl)

function ProcessFolder {
    param($folderUrl)
    $folder = $web.GetFolder($folderUrl)
    foreach ($file in $folder.Files) {
        #Ensure destination directory
        $destinationfolder = $destination + "/" + $folder.Url 
        if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationfolder))
        {
            $dest = New-Item $destinationfolder -type directory 
        }
        #Download file
        $binary = $file.OpenBinary()
        $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destinationfolder + "/" + $file.Name), Create
        $writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
        $writer.write($binary)
        $writer.Close()
        }
}

#Download root files
ProcessFolder($list.RootFolder.Url)
#Download files in folders
foreach ($folder in $list.Folders) {
    ProcessFolder($folder.Url)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this workaround yet works (seems to be obsolete based on the comments [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/lystavlen/archive/2011/10/06/how-to-access-a-office-365-document-library-from-windows-explorer.aspx)), but you should be able to map the document library as a local drive, for example, O:, and then use the `Copy-Item` cmdlet to copy the entire folder structure recursively (see [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/07/04/powertip-use-powershell-to-copy-items-and-retain-folder-structure.aspx)):

```
Copy-Item O:\ –destination '\\GRAPE\Documents\migrated' -recurse -container
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look here for the CSOM PowerShell to download files from SPO https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-automactically-1bc0ddd6 or use **OfficeDevPnP PowerShell** https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-PowerShell highly recommended!

Comment: how to use pnp powershell in  an on-premises version of SP 2013? i dont have SPO, so, would like to know whether the pnp-powershell from the above link, can be used for on-prem version as well.

Comment: It can. It works for 2013/2016/2019 and SPO.